# Change legend labels in ggsurvfit ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, survival-analysis, survival

I am doing a Kaplan-Meier using ggsurvfit. This is my code

```
p <- survfit2(Surv(time, death)~female, data=df) 

p %>%
ggsurvfit(type = "survival", linewidth=1) +
  labs(
      title = "Kaplan-Meier Curve",
      y = "Survival probability",
      x = "Time, days") + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,30)) +
  add_legend_title("Sex") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 5,10,15,20,25,30)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01,0)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('dodgerblue2', 'orchid2')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('dodgerblue2', 'orchid2')) +
  theme_gray() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  add_censor_mark() +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable(risktable_group = "risktable_stats") + 
  add_pvalue(caption="Log-rank {p.value}",
             location = "annotation", x =4, y=0.10) +
  add_quantile(x_value = 30, linetype = "dotted", color = "grey30", linewidth = 0.8) + 
  add_risktable_strata_symbol(symbol = "\U25CF", size = 10)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to change the legend labels in the legend, as they appear like this:

[image]

On the website of ggsurvfit it is written that "Publishable Legends: Raw variable names do not appear in the figure legend, e.g. "sex=Female"" and also on the examples there is Male and Female (see below), however I cannot manage to do the same and I don't know what to write.

[image]

Can please someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `labels` argument in `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_color_manual` to pass your label names. This is not specific to `ggsurvfit`, but is true for all ggplot-based plots

```r
p <- survfit2(Surv(time, status)~sex, data=lung) 

p %>%
  ggsurvfit(type = "survival", linewidth=1) +
  labs(
    title = "Kaplan-Meier Curve",
    y = "Survival probability",
    x = "Time, days") + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,30)) +
  add_legend_title("Sex") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 5,10,15,20,25,30)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01,0)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('dodgerblue2', 'orchid2'),
                     labels = c('My label', 'My other label')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('dodgerblue2', 'orchid2'),
                    labels = c('My label', 'My other label')) +
  theme_gray() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  add_censor_mark() +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable(risktable_group = "risktable_stats") + 
  add_pvalue(caption="Log-rank {p.value}",
             location = "annotation", x =4, y=0.10) +
  add_quantile(x_value = 30, linetype = "dotted", 
               color = "grey30", linewidth = 0.8) + 
  add_risktable_strata_symbol(symbol = "\U25CF", size = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: I have one problem though. If I change the option to put the variable instead of the dots in the risk table, there is still 0 and 1 instead of the labels I put.

Comment: The code I put is the following in the line "add table" (and also I deleted the last line "add_risktable_strata..."): add_risktable(risktable_height = 0.25,
                theme = 
                  list(
                    theme_risktable_boxed(axis.text.y.size = 11, 
                                            plot.title.size = 11),
                    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"))
                  )) +

Comment: I solved it by creating a new column in the dataset, so that sex==1 ~ "Female", although I noticed that the colours are reversed because as far as I noticed the letter F comes before M so the blue corresponders to F, but it is easily solvable